# How to extract invoice dates from text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Text extracted from pdf contains dates after word Date or Date: (may be in lower case and may or may not contain : in end ) and date in format 99.99.999 (leading zeroes may skipped) . Date may be also in next line.

Date after words Date:, date, date: should extracted, it may be in next line also. Date is always in d.m.yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy, d.mm.yyyy or dd.m.yyyy format separated buy dots.

Examples:

```
Invoice date 03.04.2023

date 03.04.2023

Date: 3.4.2023

Inv. date
03.04.2023
```

Trying to find match using

```
var text=@"    aaaa vvvv: 202305001
  XXXXX YYYYY xxx
  Inv. date:  1.05.2023
  Bula 14a
  Due:  10.05.2023
";

var dateexp = "^.*(?i)Date(.|\n)*\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d.*\n";

    var rida = Regex.Match(tekst, dateexp, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    if (!rida.Success)
      throw new Exception();
```

does not find match.
How to find those dates?

Using C#  .NET 7 ASP.NET MVC controller.

Comment: Have you tried \d{1,2} instead of \d\d ?

Comment: You did not capture the date. Wrap the date part with parentheses. And never use `(.|\n)*`, always use `.*` or `.*?` with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. `(?si)^.*Date.*?(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}).*` and then grab `rida.Groups[1].Value` after finding the match.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and experience): Does the PDF only have one text layer? No xml? Or is this from OCR of the image in the PDF?

Comment: in the text, you have Inv. date and due, which date do you want to extract, or is it both? is it always day, month, and year order or does it changes?

Comment: Date after words Date:, date, date: should extracted, it may be in next line also. Date is always in d.m.yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy, d.mm.yyyy or dd.m.yyyy format separated buy dots. I added this to question

Comment: When you know the set of formats then i wouldn't use Regex. DateTime.ParseExact has an overload that takes an array of formats to use for parsing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-8.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles)

Comment: @Ralf Invoice may contain different dates in different places. I need to know which date should parsed. Proper date has word similar to Date:  before it.

Comment: Make it simple :             string pattern = @"date:\s+(?'date'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

Comment: So its not sufficient to find the keywords like "date:", "due:" and throw the next word into DateTime.ParseExact? For me it means if you Regex more including date dates not fitting will be ignored. Combining Regex with DateTime.ParseExact will lead to getting an error on unexpected datetimes. That seems way more failsafe to me.

Comment: It is sufficient to find date after date word. However there may be colon after date or date may be next line. after date is found, parsing is applied.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, great comment. __(?si)^.*Date.*?(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}).*__ with SingleLine option seems to work.

Comment: Note that the first `^.*` is only needed if you expect several dates in the string, and you need to get the last match. Else, just remove `^.*` from the pattern. Last `.*` can be removed unconditionally. So, `(?si)Date.*?(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})` can be the best solution.

Comment: Works great. I added also __\b__ to your regexp: __(?si)\bDate.*?(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})__ from answer. Is this safer, it discards words like SomeDate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the regular expression to match the date formats and the word "Date" in any case (lowercase or uppercase) followed by a colon or not. Here is an updated regular expression that should match the dates in the formats you mentioned:

```
(?i)\bDate\b:?[\r\n\s]*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `(?i)` - Ignore case flag
- `\bDate\b` - Matches the word "Date" surrounded by word boundaries
- `:?` - Matches an optional colon
- `[\r\n\s]*` - Matches any combination of newline, carriage return or whitespace characters
- `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}` - Matches the date in the formats d.m.yyyy, dd.mm.yyyy, d.mm.yyyy or dd.m.yyyy separated by dots.

Here's how you can use this regular expression in C# to extract the date:

```cs
var text = @"    aaaa vvvv: 202305001
  XXXXX YYYYY xxx
  Inv. date:  1.05.2023
  Bula 14a
  Due:  10.05.2023
";

var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)\bDate\b:?[\r\n\s]*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}");

var match = regex.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value.Trim(), "d.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // Outputs: 2023-05-01
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No match found.");
}
```

This code will extract the date from the text and parse it into a `DateTime` object using the `ParseExact` method. The `Trim` method is used to remove any leading or trailing whitespace characters from the matched string. The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` parameter is used to specify the date format. Finally, the date is printed in the desired format using the `ToString` method.

Comment: `[\r\n\s]` = `\s`.